Why does my lambda function cause a resource leak in Java (using Quarkus)?
I have a Quarkus microservice (let's call it A) which makes a POST request to another microservice (let's call it B) using the RestClient. If A makes a request to B, but B is down (i.e. not started yet), then microservice A is automatically stopped by Quarkus due to an unhandled exception, which is normal behaviour. To fix this without having to wrap every call in a try-catch block I have tried the following:
I tried using the @ClientExceptionMapper but that did not work for this exception. In my understanding because thist ClientExceptionMapper handles RuntimeExceptions, while the exception I am encountering is a ProcessException as seen in the debugger output:
2024-04-19 11:49:21,649 ERROR [io.qua.run.Application] (Quarkus Main Thread) Failed to start application (with profile [dev]): jakarta.ws.rs.ProcessingException: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: localhost/127.0.0.1:8081
So to handle this exception without having to write a try-catch block around every HTTP request in my microservice (which is honestly not often, but I want to learn something new), I decided to wrap the function call in a utility method using lambda expressions.
So instead of: testClient.makePost(someDataClass);
it becomes:  ClientUtilities.handleConnectionRefused(() -> testClient.makePost(someDataClass));
Where the ClientUtilities is defined as follows:
package org.acme.rest.client;

import java.net.ConnectException;
import java.util.function.Supplier;
import jakarta.ws.rs.ProcessingException;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.Response;

public class ClientUtilities {
    public static Response handleConnectionRefused(Supplier<Response> restClientCall) {
        Response response = null;
        try {
            response = restClientCall.get();
        } catch (ProcessingException e) {
            if (e.getCause() instanceof ConnectException) {
                // Handle connection refused error
                System.out.println("Connection refused: " + e.getMessage());
                return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).build();
            } else {
                // Handle other errors
                throw e;
            }
        } finally {
            if (response != null) {
                response.close();
            }
        }
        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).build();
    }
}

This fixes the application shutdown, because the exception is now handled. But it generates a warning inside my IDE (which is VS Code).
The warning is Resource leak: '<unassigned Closeable value>' is never closed given at this line ClientUtilities.handleConnectionRefused(() -> testClient.makePost(someDataClass));. Specifically the part of testClient.makePost(someDataClass)
As I am still new to Java (Computer Science Student) and willing to learn and explore programming concepts, the chance that I made a mistake is high. I tried to do some research on this topic, but did not become any wiser.
I have uploaded a sample project at Github which demonstrates this problem.
I wish to know why this warning arises and if possible how to correctly implement my solution so it does not generate a warning and thus becomes less prone to a resource leak.
UPDATE 1: updated ClientUtilities with suggestions by ChaosFire, but warning remains with try with resources:
package org.acme.rest.client;

import java.net.ConnectException;
import java.util.function.Supplier;
import jakarta.ws.rs.ProcessingException;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.Response;

public class ClientUtilities {
    public static Response handleConnectionRefused(Supplier<Response> restClientCall) {
        try( Response response = restClientCall.get()) {
            return response;
        } catch (ProcessingException e) {
            if (e.getCause() instanceof ConnectException) {
                // Handle connection refused error
                System.out.println("Connection refused: " + e.getMessage());
                return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).build();
            } else {
                // Handle other errors
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }
}

UPDATE 2: I changed the return type of handleConnectionRefused() from Response tot void as it made no functional difference for my usecase and suppressed the warning. The problem is solved.

Your method returns a Response, which is AutoClosable, but you never handle that. Two more things - 1) Use try-with-resources in your utility method, since you are using jakarta, you must be at least on java 17. 2) Your utility does not return the response from the rest call, but something you build yourself, this seems fishy.

@Chaosfire Thanks for your reply! I updated my code (as seen in the main question). I hope I am understanding your suggestions correctly, but the warning remains in my editor.

it makes no sense to return a closable resource, which renders your try-with-resource block useless. I would add a Consumer-arg to the method, and pass the 'response' in there. Thus the resource would be closed controllably

@injecteer It was indeed a mistake to code the handleConnectionRefused() with a return type of Response, as this is not necessary for my use-case. I changed the return type of the function to void and all is well now.
